# Immediate ES6 export (React, Webpack, Babel)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

At the root of a directory (e.g. `components/`, `containers/`), I have an `index.jsx` file which immediately exports out all components, so that I can import them like so:

```
    import {SampleOne, SampleTwo} from '../components'.
```

However, the root `index.jsx` file doesn't work with the following:

```
    import SampleOne from './SampleOne/SampleOne';
    import SampleTwo from './Sample/SampleTwo';

    export default {
      SampleOne,
      SampleTwo  
    };
```

So, I converted it to the following (which is basically the same):

```
    export {default as SampleOne} from './SampleOne/SampleOne';
    export {default as SampleTwo} from './SampleTwo/SampleTwo';
```

This works, however, I get this warning:

```
    Can't make class (SampleOne & SampleTwo) hot reloadable due to being read-only.
    To fix this you can try two solutions. First, you can exclude files or directories
    (for example, /node_modules/) using 'exclude' option in loader configuration.
    Second, if you are using Babel, you can enable loose mode for `es6.modules` using
    the 'loose' option. See: http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/loose/
    and http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/
```

Comment: There can only be one `default` export.

Comment: @zeroflagL: Do you see more than one?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @FelixKling I was confused by the shorthand syntax in the first example and the statement _"basically the same". At second sight the two versions are different. The first version exports a single object as default whereas the second one has two named exports.

Comment: Yes, the syntax for exporting with default that way works the same way as the other. In fact, as mentioned, that one actually works where the other does not.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of head-banging, we replaced

```
export {default as SampleOne} from './SampleOne/SampleOne';
export {default as SampleTwo} from './SampleTwo/SampleTwo';
```

with

```
import {default as SampleOne} from './SampleOne/SampleOne';
import {default as SampleTwo} from './SampleTwo/SampleTwo';

export {SampleOne, SampleTwo};
```

and that seems to be working for us.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem since I'm using a index.js in each modules to export all submodules like this:

```
export {default as SampleOne} from './SampleOne/SampleOne';
export {default as SampleTwo} from './SampleTwo/SampleTwo';
```

According to [the discussion in the react-hot-loader repo](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/158), you can either ignore it(since it still got loaded) or don't re-export the modules.