# Consolidating Bundles in Webpack 2 with System.import

Tags: javascript, webpack

In Webpack 1, we do code-splitting imports with `require.ensure`, which can take an array of modules.  These modules are combined into a single bundle and fetched with one HTTP request:

```
require.ensure(['module1', 'module2'], (require) => {
    const module1 = require('module1');
    const module2 = require('module2');

    // use these modules here...
});

// ==> both modules are served as a single bundle, e.g. '5.js'
```

With Webpack 2, we can now use `System.import` for a cleaner syntax... but it seems like System.import only accepts a single module to import.  Fine -- I can use `Promise.all` -- but then I end up with two bundles:

```
Promise.all([
    System.import('module1'),
    System.import('module2')
]).then( (module1, module2) => {

    // use these modules here...
});

// ==> each module served as its own bundle, e.g. '5.js', '6.js'
```

**Is there a way to use `System.import` but still combine the requested modules into a single bundle?**

(Yes, in some cases I can add a new module file that in turn imports and consumes both the dependencies, and that's often the best approach, but for several of my use cases it merely adds additional boilerplate)

Answer (score 1):

[According to Sean T. Larkin (webpack core team)](https://twitter.com/brandonjboone/status/791446563004571653), using a single file that imports both resources is your best bet (*like you already discovered*).

### Example *(untested)*

#### bundle.js

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/36878745/402706
export {default as module1} from './modules/module1';
export {default as module2} from './modules/module2';
```

#### Import the single file

```
System.import('bundle').then({ module1, module2 } => {
    // do stuff
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Chunk loading failed");
});
```

However, there's no disadvantage to using `require.ensure` as you have it other than,

> not being able to handle async load fails via a promise. [src](https://twitter.com/TheLarkInn/status/791459903156031488)

He mentioned future changes that, "[may help with this](https://twitter.com/TheLarkInn/status/791456419807502336)," but I didn't press for what those might be.

Answer (score -1):

I hope that answer helps you...
I had the same problem to do dynamic module loading and archieve that combining an app folder as root context of webpack 2 and the Ignore plugin because I didn't understand the ContextReplacementPlugin. But that work doesn't bundle all in a single file.

Here's the snippet:

```
import angular from 'angular';

var paths = ["components/app.components.js", "shared/app.shared.js"];

Promise.all(paths.map(path => System.import('../app/' + path))).then(modules => {
    let dependencies = [];
    modules.forEach(module => {
        dependencies.push(module.default.name);
    })
    angular.module("app", dependencies);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error.message)
});
```

Using this structure you can fetch an api then use it for dynamic loading for example.

Then in webpack I used IgonorePlugin to avoid *.html files from webpack build:

```
  plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/vertx/),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/[A-Za-z]*\.(html)$/i)
    ],
```

Here is the project github: https://github.com/yurikilian/angular1es6